# Multi Branching in Microsoft Workflow Foundation 4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, parallels

I’m working on a BPMS project with WF4. For implementing human activities I used custom native activity that executes several functionality. A book mark is created with it. WF instance is persisted and workflow will be unload for next call.

Exactly my problem is fork-joint in workflow foundation 4. I don’t know how I can do it.
I found that parallel activity execute each child activity of itself and when all of them are finished workflow can be continued also know about pick branch and it’s functionality, But in my project there are another kind of activity that it’s like parallel and branching activity.

I want to have multiple branch of sequence that can work with each other and go to en without any dependency to other sequence. I think it’s like multiple instance workflows also I need to join branches in some situation and it’s fork-join. May be one of the branches go to the end of workflow but another is on the middle of sequence.
Dose wf4 support multi-branching ? Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

WF4 doesn't support fork-joins. You need to model this using a Parallel activity and/or custom activities with bookmarks.